# How to automatically boot without asking for username and password?

Tags: boot

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm new to it.
Every time I turn on the computer Ubuntu asks for username & password to log in, I don't want that to happen & I just want it to log in automatically without asking about username and password, What should I do?
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to ubuntu!

Go to "System Settings" -> "user accounts" and check the box for auto login.
That's it.